# how to get total and total of subset using mysql?

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to have a mysql query return a calculated result, but am having some challenges as I am only able to get it to return 1 value.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e9276/1

Is it possible to get total count for agents that are robot types within a department, and then the total of agents within department to calculate %?

example:
department 1, has 4 out of 5 robots. (80% robots)

the type field may not always have the same value, but will contain at least the keyword 'robot' or 'human'.

I know I can get the % programmatically, but wanted to check if there was a way to do this directly using mysql query.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
  department, 
  SUM(type LIKE '%robot%') robots, 
  COUNT(department) total, 
  SUM(type LIKE '%robot%') / COUNT(department) robot_percentage
FROM agents
GROUP BY department;
```

[Example SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e9276/16)

To format the `robot_percentage` with percent sign you coud do:

```
CONCAT(FORMAT( (SUM(type LIKE '%robot%')*100 / COUNT(department)),2),'%') robot_percentage
```

Comment: that worked great. i did not realize i can use LIKE within the SUM function.

Comment: @Rick Yeah, that's a neat trick. You can use any expression that returns a boolean true/false value.

Comment: is there a way to use REGEXP within the SUM?

Comment: @Rick since regexp returns 1 or 0 it should work fine; haven't tried it though.

Comment: after further research, mysql has limited compatibility with regexp capabilities. Will probably extract the result and leverage php to massage the data using regexp.